# VaryByParam Does Not Appear to Work

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a web form with the following in the code behind:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

int _pGID = base.GetParamAsInt("PGID");

if (_pGID > 0)
{
  Response.Write(...);
}
else
{
  Response.Write(...);
}

Response.End();
```

And the following mark up:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PG.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="PG" %>

<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="PGID" %>
```

The problem is that the the page_load event fires every time the page is requested, even if the QueryString 'PGID' parameter is the same.

I am missing something regarding how to use the VaryByParam attribute?

Comment: You're manually handling the page render so far I see on your code. My guess (and just a guess) is that since you're not letting the asp.net page to follow the normal flow (you manually end the request calling Response.End()), the output cache is not active for the page. Try to test without the manual response handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a break form the code and doing some more testing, it seems the call to Response.End() is causing the problem.  From a few articles Response.Flush() will also cause the same issue.